# NestJS JWT Strategy authentication. Payload is signed with same secure key for all users

Tags: node.js, jwt, nestjs, passport-jwt

As documentation of NestJS for authentication using Passport JWT, the flow is as below:

1. Client login with username/password
2. If username/password is valid, JWT sign payload (use preconfigured secure key) to create access token and return this access token to client
3. Client use access token to request guarded resources

So if secure key to sign payload is hacked, the access token can be generated for ALL users without using password.

Is my above understand is correct? What is suggestion for more secure?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if the key is compromised, the attacker can generate keys for themselves.

Try to adopt a more secure storage for credentials. If it has some sort of key rotation mechanism, it would be even better. For example, I use [AWS Secrets Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/) for this purpose in my project.